# When did disabilities begin to become recognized?

Tags: cultural-history, social-history

I know that even to this day disabled individuals are often discriminated against and are treated unfairly. At what point in time, were disabilities first understood at a broad societal level? What cultural changes facilitated this?

Comment: Related: [What do written sources say about disability in early civilisations?](http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/10023/what-do-written-sources-say-about-disability-in-early-civilisations)

Comment: @called2voyage Was that for long or short term disabilities?

Comment: [Crutches date back to at least 2830 BC](http://iwalk-free.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Clinical-evaluation-comparing-standard-crutches.pdf), implying some level of cultural support for disability.

Comment: I believe it was both, but I don't have a reference on hand to back that up.

Comment: [A 12 year old girl with a deformed skull from at least 350,000 years ago suggests care for the permanently disabled among Neanderthals or a related species.](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg22029462-600-oldest-human-genome-dug-up-in-spains-pit-of-bones/)

Answer (score 3):

The modern culmination of recognition for disabled people in modern times was the [Americans With Disabilities Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americans_with_Disabilities_Act_of_1990) of 1990, which mandated (among other things) "reasonable accommodation" in public places for disabled people, while prohibiting discrimination against such people. (Variations of the ADA have been transplanted to other countries.)

The ADA was passed by Congressional leaders of the so-called [Silent Generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Generation), such as Senator Edward ("Ted) Kennedy. (A few years earlier, a similarly led Congress voted to give compensation to Japanese-Americans interned during World War II.) This was the "Civil Rights" generation (of Martin Luther King, Bobby Kennedy, etc.) that first made their mark as young adults in the 1960s. This was a time of widespread and growing sympathy and understanding for traditionally disadvantaged groups such as women, minorities, and yes, the disabled.

Comment: The [Rehabilitation Act of 1973](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_504_of_the_Rehabilitation_Act) was the first major law recognizing disabilities in the US, though I would agree the ADA is more distinctive.

Comment: @cat40: I used the term, "the modern culmination" to describe the ADA. Take that for whatever you want. I did not describe it as the "first major law."

Comment: I know, I just thought I should mention it since I can't add my own answer. I'm not criticizing your answer.